# Hibernate HQL: two levels of joins

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql

I am new to HQL and have the following table relationships:

- `Term` has many `Definitions`
- `Definition` has many `DefinitionProducts`
- `DefinitionProducts` has one `Product`

I want to get the list of `Terms` that have at least one `Definition` that has at least one `DefinitionProduct` that has a specific `Product`

This is my best attempt (in Grails):

```
Term.findAll("from Term t, Definition d inner join t.definitions def,  
def.definitionProducts dp where ? = some elements (dp.product)",
Product.get(1))
```

With the above, I get a "def.definitionProducts is not mapped" exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***select t*** from Term t join t.definitions def join def.definitionProducts dp where dp.product=?

Comment: That seems to return a list of definitionProducts

Comment: select t from Term t join t.definitions def join def.definitionProducts dp where dp.product=?

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot. In grails, I just had to switch the call from Term.findAll to Term.executeQuery and it worked!